# How to deploy Angular cli 7 app on Azure using Visual Studio code?

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I created an Angular app using angular-cli(node 8.12) and build it:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli7

ng new my-app

ng build --prod  //inside folder
```

i connect my visual studio code to my azure account then i create the service app and then just right click on my project and select Publish Web App then select my dist folder and deploy it.
VS say that all is completed and i see my dist folder but if i browse there i see the default page.
how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you trying to Publish to an Azure Web App? Have you imported the Publish Profile?

Comment: what do you mean? my profile of azure inside VS?

Comment: https://sajeetharan.com/2020/02/14/deploy-angular9-app-to-azure-with-github-actions/